# Aerospike Java spark connector

Tags: java, apache-spark, aerospike

I am trying out aerospike as an alternative for cassandra. But I am not able to find a proper aerospark java connector or any example how to load and save rdd or dataframes in java (found lot of examples in scala.) .

Is there any tutorial or examples available for java spark connector to load and save data to aerospike. (I found this connector https://github.com/sasha-polev/aerospark but not enough documentation) .

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to look at the GitHub repo [aerospike/aerospark](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospark), which forked off the sasha-polev one, and got rewritten and expanded.

The [Aerospike Spark Connector](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/connectors/spark) has support for RDD, DataFrames and SparkSQL. It's an active project with a great [tutorial](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/connectors/spark/tutorial.html) on the Aerospike site.